# Factorial Limit

Tags: limits, analysis

So I'm trying to prove the following: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}, n\geq k$$

I've taken the assumption that given the summation of two limits extending to infinity over the same variable $n$, I take that 
$$\frac{1}{k!} \approx \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!n^{k}}$$ with some light expansion of the right-hand side and shifting of terms i have that 
$$\frac{1}{k!} \approx \frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^{k}}\cdot \frac{1}{k!}$$ 
Which implies that:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^{k}}=1 \Rightarrow or \Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1)}{n^{k-1}}=1$$
This is where I got stuck..any help is much appreciated in advance. Thanks

Comment: You should state the original claim more clearly. It seems like you are wanting to take $k \to \infty$ and $n \to \infty$, but this is not stated concretely anywhere. The statement won't make sense if $k > n$, since then $\binom{n}{k}$ is undefined. Regarding the last limit in your post, that limit is indeed $1$ if $k$ is *fixed* while $n \to \infty$.

Comment: I'm not sure how to formally show that it converges to precisely 1. I was thinking possibly the definition of the limit bounded by some epsilon.

Comment: You can take separately take the limit of $\frac{n-1}{n}$, $\frac{n-2}{n}$, etc. and note that each limit is $1$. Again, this assumes $k$ is fixed.

Comment: Note that even should you prove it, this shows only that the nth terms of the summation approach  each other. This is very different from the series being equal.

Comment: The left-hand limit is clearly $e$. The right hand sum, for fixed $n$, is the binomial expansion of $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sum_\limits{k=0}^n {n\choose k} \frac {1}{n^k}$ is the expansion of $(1+\frac 1n)^n$

We might write it out like so:

$1 + n(\frac 1n) + \frac {n(n-1)}{2}(\frac 1{n^2})+\cdots\\
1 + 1 + \frac 12 (1-\frac 1n)+ \frac 1{3!}(1-\frac 1n)(1-\frac 2n)\cdots$

We can match term by term with $\sum_\limits{k=0}^n \frac {1}{k!}$

When $n$ is finite, every term in 
$\sum_\limits{k=0}^n {n\choose k} \frac {1}{n^k}$ is less  than its corresponding term in $\sum_\limits{k=0}^n  \frac {1}{k!}$

When $n$ is finite

$\sum_\limits{k=0}^n {n\choose k} \frac {1}{n^k} < \sum_\limits{k=0}^n  \frac {1}{k!}$

Consider, $\sum_\limits{k=0}^m {n\choose k} \frac {1}{n^k}$ with $m<n$ i.e. the first $m$ terms of the expansion of $(1+\frac 1n)^n$

$1 + 1 + \frac 12 (1-\frac 1n)+ \frac 1{3!}(1-\frac 1n)(1-\frac 2n)+\cdots +\frac 1{m!}(1-\frac 1n)(1-\frac 2n)\cdot(1-\frac {m-1}n)$

letting $n$ get big

$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \sum_\limits{k=0}^m {n\choose k} \frac {1}{n^k} = \sum_\limits{k=0}^m \frac 1{m!}$

And then we get let $m$ get to be as big as we need it to be.